# keep alignment under enumerate

Tags: spacing, enumerate, line-spacing, multicol

I would like to keep the indentation for my fraction that appears below my first item however i don't know how to align it if itself is not an item.
source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=558pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1.]
\item Simplify the following:
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} (a)]
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{3}$ \\
    \quad $\displaystyle \frac{6}{3}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2}{5}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and the displayed output:
[image: 1]
what i want:
[image: 2]
I also feel like /quad is a sloppy solution to add spacing after enumerate and also not entirely sure how to add more space after and before the fractions ie:
[image: 3]

someone suggested adjsuting the \baselineskip to increase this space, not really sure how to do that though.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `enumitem` package with `shortlabels` option so as to emulate the behaviour of `enumerate` package. Now you can adjust the `itemsep`, `left margin` etc easily. Further, instead of using `\\`, use `\par` followed by some `\vspace{<length>}`. I used `\bigskip`.  You can also avoid the repetitive use of `\quad` by using `labelsep=<length>` as noted by Peter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=558pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}    %%% << --- emulates enumerate package
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1.]
\item Simplify the following:
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} (a),labelsep=5mm,itemsep=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=*]
    \item $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{3}$ \par\bigskip
    $\displaystyle \frac{6}{3}$
    \item  $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2}{5}$
    \item $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$
    \item $\displaystyle \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are loading `amsmath`, you can simply use `\dfrac{}{}` instead of `\displaystyle \frac{}{}`.

Answer (score 1):

The preceding code  can be simplified with `\everymath{\displaystyle}`, and `\par\bigskip
    $\displaystyle \frac{6}{3}$`can be replaced with two `\item[]`, which gives a better vertical spacing.

In addition I give a solution that uses the `shortlst` package that allows for a `horizontal` numbering.

Here are the three solutions (2½ I'd rather say) in one file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=558pt, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} %%% << --- emulates enumerate package
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{shortlst}

\newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][3]{%
\settowidth{\qquad\labelwidth}{\labelenumi}\setlength{\labelsep}{0.8em}%
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{\dimexpr\leftmargini + \labelwidth\relax}%
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/#1-\leftmarginii\relax}%
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\color{MidnightBlue}(\alph{enumii})}
\begin{spacing}{2}
\begin{shortenumerate}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}\end{spacing}}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} 1.]
\item Simplify the following:
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} (a),labelsep=5mm,itemsep=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=*]
    \item $ \frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{3} $%
    \item[]$ \frac{6}{3}$
    \item $ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} $
    \item $ \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2}{5} $
    \item[]
    \item $ \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4} $
    \item $ \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2} $
    \item $ \frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3} $
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\item Simplify the following:
\begin{multicols}{3}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{enumerate}[\color{MidnightBlue} (a),labelsep=5mm,itemsep=0.5\baselineskip,leftmargin=*]
    \item $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{3}$ \par\bigskip
    $ \frac{6}{3}$
    \item $ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} $
    \item $ \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2}{5} $
    \item $ \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4} $
    \item $ \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2} $
    \item $ \frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3} $
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\item Simplify the following:
\begin{tabenumerate}[3]%
    \item $\begin{array}[t]{@{}l}\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{3}\\ \frac{6}{3}\medskip\end{array} $
    \item $ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} $
    \item $ \frac{4}{3} + \frac{2}{5} $
    \item $ \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4} $
    \item $ \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{2} $
    \item $ \frac{5}{6} + \frac{2}{3} $
\end{tabenumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document} 
$\displaystyle \frac{6}{3}$
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response i really appreciate it especially the syntax tips