# \displaystyle for a part of the document

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, enumerate, enumitem, displaystyle

Is there a way to use \displaystyle for a part of my document? I do not want to change everywhere the inline math sizes, on the other hand it is a bit tedious to write everywhere (in a list of examples might be 60 times) \displaystyle.

In order to give you a minimal example:

I would like to typeset the following code without writing in every line \displaystyle.

```
\begin{enumerate}   
            \item $\displaystyle \sin \frac{1}{x},\quad x\in (0,1]$
            \item $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin x},\quad x\in \left[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right]$
            \item $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sin x},\quad x\in \left[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$
\end{enumerate}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well. Obviously the cheapest and easiest solution is copy and paste. You might be able to define an abbreviated command for `\displaystyle` but that sounds like it's probably a bad idea. However, in none of your examples is `\displaystyle` really needed I don't think. You could just use `\dfrac` to get the larger fractions. If you really want them. The fact that you're in a list means displaying your maths is - well, it's generally advised against, I think

Comment: although the question isn't identical, the answer here suggesting `\everymath{\displaystyle}` might be helpful: [keep alignment under enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180267/579).  you'll want to limit it by keeping it in a group (`\begingroup ... \endgroup` should do it.)

Comment: \newcommand{\math}[1]{$\displaystyle #1$} only 5 more keystrokes than $ $

Comment: @Au101: You are right... of corse i have more complicated examples... like $\frac{\tan x + \sin \frac{1}{x}}{\{x\} - |x|\frac{\sin x}{x^2+x+1}}$ but i did not want to bother you with these details.

Comment: @barbara beeton:Your advice changes everywhere the inline math formatting.

Comment: @John Kormylo: reasonable solution, but still not satisfactionary (if i have 6 times 60 examples and everywhere i would use +3 character for begining and +3 for ending than i would have +2160 characters... so a lot of...)

Comment: @Alex -- `\everymath` is not supposed to be global; at least it's not designated as global in the texbook.  therefore, if it's invoked *within a group*, it should revert to its earlier status when the group is closed.  here's another approach: \newcommand{\domathdisplaystyle}{\bgroup\everymath{\displaystyle}} \newcommand{\undomathdisplaystyle}{\egroup}`, and then put the `\do...` before the section you want in display style, and `\undo...` after.  or you could even create a modified `enumerate`.  the scoping is the important thing.

Comment: @barbara beeton -- Now i see your point! Thanks for deeper explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\everymath{\displaystyle}`.  To make it local, put it inside a group:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Text style: $\frac{a}{b}$

\bgroup
\everymath{\displaystyle}
Display style: $\frac{a}{b}$
\egroup

And back: $\frac{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah, my suggestion; but you've showed how to do it and that it works.

Answer (score 9):

With the `etoolbox` and/or `enumitem` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}%
        \item $\sin \frac{1}{x},\quad x\in (0,1]$
        \item $\frac{1}{\sin x},\quad x\in \left[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right]$
        \item $ \frac{x}{\sin x},\quad x\in \left[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you want this just for one environment, you can use this (without `etoolbox`) instead:

```
\begin{enumerate}[before=\everymath{\displaystyle}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you want write math equation in displaystyle mode without write continuously "displaystyle" you must these three lines in preamble.

```
\let\oldfrac=\frac
    \renewcommand{\frac}[2]{\oldfrac{\displaystyle{#1}}{\displaystyle{#2}}}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

AN EXAMPLE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldfrac=\frac
\renewcommand{\frac}[2]{{\oldfrac{\displaystyle{#1}}{\displaystyle{#2}}}
\begin{document}
$e=\frac{\sum_{a}^{n}x^2}{n}$
$f=\oldfrac{1}{\sum_{1}^{m}y^2}$
\end{document}
```

if you want write the fraction using old style you must use the "oldfrac" as show the previous example:

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You actually don't need `\ensuremath` because `\frac` is supposed to be used in math mode only. Also, `\displaystyle` is a switch and it doesn't take arguments, so the braces surrounding `#1` and `#2` are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `\dfrac` macro offered in `amsmath` package.  It stands for "displaystyle fraction".