# How to have nice-looking symbols within an \itemize environment?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, itemize

I need to list some formulae within an `\itemize` environment, but my mathematical symbols look ugly since they are in inline math mode after each `\item`. How can I make them look better?

As an example, consider

```
\begin{itemize}
        \item $\prod_{a\geq5} \frac{a}{2} \int_2^\pi \frac{dt}{\sin t}$
        \item $\prod_{b\geq5} \frac{b}{2} \int_2^\pi \frac{dt}{\cos t}$
        ...
\end{itemize}
```

which renders as

[image]

but I want the `\item`s to render rather as

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `\item  $\displaystyle ...$` might result in the desired output

Comment: What you are looking for is 'displaystyle'. ,There is surely a better solution by customizing the itemize list, but the simplest way is to add `\displaystyle ` just after the first  $.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260414/134144 might also be interesting regarding a slightly more automated solution using the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the math formulas *in the `itemize` only* be shown as display style, just do like the comments: use `\displaystyle` before each math formula.

But it seems to me that you are trying to change *all* math formulas in the whole document to display style. In that case, add the following line to your preamble:

```
\everymath{\displaystyle}
```

and you will get what you want without putting any `\displaystyle`.

Comment: Why do you think OP wants to change *all* math formulas?

Comment: @Sigur You can imagine a document in which all **in-line** math formulas in `itemize` are in display style but the rest **in-line** math formulas are in in-line style. It's terrible and clearly inconsistent.

Comment: So I think the post owner wants to change all **in-line** math formulas. :)

Comment: Well, I can imagine how strange would be a documet with around 10 pages, a lot of inline math and some few items, maybe 4 lists with 2 items each, and all inline with display style! `\frac` inline display style is too big, IMHO.