# Why are there no \dint or \dsum like \dfrac?

Tags: macros, amsmath, inline, displaystyle

*This was inspired by [How to have nice-looking symbols within an \itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460448/how-to-have-nice-looking-symbols-within-an-itemize-environment) and [Sigur's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460448/how-to-have-nice-looking-symbols-within-an-itemize-environment#comment1158038_460452) which remind me about the display style of math formulas and the fractions.*

---

I know that, in the `amsmath` package there is already `\dfrac{}{}` for us to have display-style fractions (as well as `\tfrac{}{}` for in-line fraction).

[image]

Then why don't `\dsum`, `\dprod`, `\dint`, etc. exist?

If they are not to exist, then why does `\dfrac` exist?

Actually, we can define, for example, `\dint` as

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\dint}{\displaystyle\int}
```

but I want to know the reason why there are no `\dint`, etc. Or can you tell me the packages in which these `\d-` are in?

Comment: Essentially because `\displaystyle\int` will make *everything* in the formula in display style. Or not work as you intend.

Comment: Of course `\dfrac` is *not* defined as `\displaystyle\frac`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command `\dfrac` exists for rendering multistory fractions, say

```
\[
\frac{\dfrac{a}{b}-\dfrac{c}{d}}{\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}
\]
```

and is not generally intended for usage in an inline formula. It is not defined using the simplistic format `\displaystyle\frac`, but rather

```
% amsmath.sty, line 214:
\newcommand{\dfrac}{\genfrac{}{}{}0}
```

where `\genfrac` is

```
% amsmath.sty, line 221:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\genfrac}[4]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1#2}%
  \edef\@tempb{\@nx\@genfrac\@mathstyle{#4}%
    \csname @@\ifx @#3@over\else above\fi
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty \else withdelims\fi\endcsname}
  \@tempb{#1#2#3}}

% amsmath.sty, line 289:
\def\@genfrac#1#2#3#4#5{{#1{\begingroup#4\endgroup#2#3\relax#5}}}
\def\@mathstyle#1{%
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty\relax
  \else\ifcase#1\displaystyle % case 0
    \or\textstyle\or\scriptstyle\else\scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi}
```

What happens with `\dfrac{a}{b}`? By definition this becomes `\genfrac{}{}{}0{a}{b}`, so

```
\def\@tempa{}%
  \edef\@tempb{\@nx\@genfrac\@mathstyle{0}%
    \csname @@\ifx @@over\else above\fi
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty \else withdelims\fi\endcsname}
  \@tempb{}{a}{b}
```

By definition of `\@mathstyle`, `\@tempb` is defined to be `\@genfrac\displaystyle\@@over`, so we're left with

```
\@genfrac\displaystyle\@@over{}{a}{b}
```

which in turn becomes

```
{\displaystyle{\begingroup a\endgroup\@@over\relax b}}
```

and `\@@over` is the primitive `\over`. Note the braces around the whole construction. You may enjoy chasing the expansion of `\frac`, `\binom` and `\dbinom`.

With `\int` one cannot do `\displaystyle\int`, because this wouldn't confine the scope of `\displaystyle`, nor `{\displaystyle\int}`, because this would not place correctly the limits. Indeed, the test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\dint}{\displaystyle\int}
\newcommand{\ddint}{\displaystyle\int}

\begin{document}

$\dint_0^1\frac{x}{2}\,dx$

$\ddint_0^1\frac{x}{2}\,dx$

\end{document}
```

produces wrong output in either case:

[image]

Can one do something about this? Yes, but I don't think it's worth the pain. Anyway, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dint}{t\limits e{_^}}{%
  \mathop{
    \displaystyle\int
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{\limits}
    \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}
    \IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\dint_0^1\frac{x}{2}\,dx$
$\dint\limits_0^1\frac{x}{2}\,dx$
$\dint\frac{x}{2}\,dx$

\end{document}
```

[image]